# Sum of the minimum elements in all connected components of an undirected graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

> In a city, there is `n` persons and each person has some friends in
>   the city. (if a is friend of b then b is also friend of a) We want to spread a rumor between these persons but saying
>   the rumor to each person has a cost `c_i` but after that, the person
>   spread the rumor between all of its friends for free.
>
> We want to find minimum cost to spread the rumor to all persons in the
>   city. In the input we get `n`: number of persons. `m`: number of relations. then `n` integers `c_i`: cost of saying the rumor to person `i` and then in `m` lines, we get two integers `u`,`v` in each line which indicates `u,v` are friends. (note that number of person start from `1` to `n` but in arrays we have from `0` to `n-1`)
>
> Also `n,m<=10E5` and `c_i<=10E9`

I think this problem is equivalent to Sum of the minimum elements in all connected components of an undirected graph.

I found a solution for it in internet with C++ but I wanted to write it in Java and so wrote the program below using dfs. The problem is that when I submit the answer to an online judge in the site where I found the question, it just pass only 3 of 20 tests. I want to know which part of my solution is wrong?

(the site is not in English and is actually an online judge system of a university but if you want it, I can link to the site)

Final Code That completely works fine:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Graph {
    int numberOfVertices;
    LinkedList<Integer>[] graph;
    boolean[] visited;
    long[] costs;

    Graph(int numberOfVertices,long[] costs) {
        this.numberOfVertices = numberOfVertices;
        this.graph = new LinkedList[numberOfVertices];
        for (int v = 0; v < numberOfVertices; v++) {
            graph[v] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }

        this.costs=costs;
        this.visited = new boolean[numberOfVertices];

    }

    void addEdge(int u, int v) {
        graph[u].add(v);
        graph[v].add(u);
    }

    long dfs(int node, long mini) {
        // Stores the minimum
        mini = Math.min(mini, costs[ node]);

        // Marks node as visited
        visited[ node] = true;

        // Traversed in all the connected nodes
        for (int i : graph[ node]) {
            if (!visited[ i])
                mini = dfs(i, mini);
        }

        return mini;
    }

    void minimumSumConnectedComponents() {
        // Initially sum is 0
        long sum = 0L;

        // Traverse for all nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                sum += dfs(i, costs[i]);
            }
        }

        // Returns the answer

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}




public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfVertices,numberOfRelations;
        numberOfVertices=input.nextInt();
        numberOfRelations=input.nextInt();
        long [] costs = new long[numberOfVertices];
        for (int i =0;i<numberOfVertices;i++)
        {
            costs[i]=input.nextLong();
        }
        Graph g = new Graph(numberOfVertices,costs);
        for (int i =0;i<numberOfRelations;i++)
        {
            int v1,v2;
            v1=input.nextInt();
            v2=input.nextInt();
            g.addEdge(v1-1,v2-1);
        }
         g.minimumSumConnectedComponents();

    }
}
```

Old Code which has some issues:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class Graph {
    Integer numberOfVertices;
    Vector<Integer>[] graph;
    boolean[] visited;
    Long[] costs;

    Graph(Integer numberOfVertices,Long[] costs) {
        this.numberOfVertices = numberOfVertices;
        this.graph = new Vector[numberOfVertices];
        for (Integer v = 0; v < numberOfVertices; v++) {
            graph[v] = new Vector<Integer>();
        }
        this.costs = new Long[numberOfVertices];
        for (Integer v = 0; v < numberOfVertices; v++) {
            this.costs[v] = costs[v];
        }
        this.visited = new boolean[numberOfVertices];

    }

    void addEdge(Integer u, Integer v) {
        graph[u].add(v);
        graph[v].add(u);
    }

    void dfs(Integer node, Long mini) {
        // Stores the minimum
        mini = Math.min(mini, costs[(Integer) node]);

        // Marks node as visited
        visited[(Integer) node] = true;

        // Traversed in all the connected nodes
        for (Integer i : graph[(Integer) node]) {
            if (!visited[(Integer) i])
                dfs(i, mini);
        }
    }

    void minimumSumConnectedComponents() {
        // Initially sum is 0
        Long sum = 0L;

        // Traverse for all nodes
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                Long mini = costs[i];
                dfs(i, mini);
                sum += mini;
            }
        }

        // Returns the answer

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}




public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer numberOfVertices,numberOfRelations;
        numberOfVertices=input.nextInt();
        numberOfRelations=input.nextInt();
        Long [] costs = new Long[numberOfVertices];
        for (Integer i =0;i<numberOfVertices;i++)
        {
            costs[i]=input.nextLong();
        }
        Graph g = new Graph(numberOfVertices,costs);
        for (Integer i =0;i<numberOfRelations;i++)
        {
            Integer v1,v2;
            v1=input.nextInt();
            v2=input.nextInt();
            g.addEdge(v1-1,v2-1);
        }
         g.minimumSumConnectedComponents();

    }
}
```

Sample Test Cases:

```
5 2
2 5 3 4 8
1 4
4 5

Expected Output: 10
```

---

```
10 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Expected Output: 55
```

---

```
10 5
1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10

Expected Output: 15
```

My program pass this sample test cases but it gets wrong answer for a lot of unknown test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines don't do what you want:

```
    // Stores the minimum
    mini = Math.min(mini, costs[(Integer) node]);
```

If they mutated the caller's `mini`, then your code seems otherwise correct (assuming no stack overflows). My suggestion would be to return the new value of `mini` for the caller to use:

```
Long dfs(Integer node, Long mini) {
    // Stores the minimum
    mini = Math.min(mini, costs[(Integer) node]);

    // Marks node as visited
    visited[(Integer) node] = true;

    // Traversed in all the connected nodes
    for (Integer i : graph[(Integer) node]) {
        if (!visited[(Integer) i])
            mini = dfs(i, mini);
    }

    return mini;
}

void minimumSumConnectedComponents() {
    // Initially sum is 0
    Long sum = 0L;

    // Traverse for all nodes
    for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        if (!visited[i]) {
            sum += dfs(i, costs[i]);
        }
    }

    // Returns the answer

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: It solved a lot of problems but now I get timelimit error in just one case. Any idea for optimization? (I think the time limit set for the problem is about 2 secs)

Comment: I solved the time limit problem by using LinkedList instead of Vector. thanks for your help in the algorithm.